# Can I hide content blocks from non signed in customers magento

Tags: php, magento, customization, b2b

Hi We want to show the home page, category pages, and product page and product RRP to all customers logged in or not. But we want to hide the main description and the actual price to all but logged in customers, as we will be a Business to business account with different prices for different customer sets.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())

{

// show My block

}
else 
{

echo 'login for more details';

}